# when two fields have same ng model how to write it's value of send key?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have two fields with same ng-model
like:

```
input field 1 type=text ng-model=text.abc

input field 2 type-text ng-model-text.abc
```

for the first input field 1 I can write

```
 var input = element(by.model('text.abc'));

 input.sendKeys('Team1');
```

what should I write for the input field 2 that the value not concatenate with input field 1?

Comment: What type is the var 'input'? Is it an object, or an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you try by this way :

```
var input = element.all(by.model('text.abc'));

 input.get(0).sendKeys('Team1');
 input.get(1).sendKeys('Team2');
```

Comment: Ok good to hear that, so accept my solution if this is what you need  ;)